# Firebase Auth UI: Is there an UI to let user edit their profile?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase Auth UI in an Android app.

I've already managed to use the UI for signin and registration of new users.
At the registration, user can set their name and password (if email provider).

I know it's possible to change the user data later via code with `UserProfileChangeRequest`, but it depends on me creating the account edit screen.

However, I want to know if there is a ready-made Firebase Auth UI that I can launch and let the user to update their data, such as name, photo, password, etc. Or if there is a way to relaunch the signup last screen step with these profile fields for edition.

Comment: Have you checked [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. But didn't find anything. FirebaseUI Auth is a module inside FirebaseUI

Comment: Which language you will using in the app? Java or Kotlin?

Comment: @Desmond I'm using Kotlin. But didn't find it neither in Kotlin or Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there're no ready-made Ui for this, by this time.

The problem I see with it, is that there are confusion on what data user want to change, he can misunderstood it as change of his google account data, if it was official Ui from Firebase.

It's not a big deal to make it originally in your project, as you already mentioned.